# ajax / php response adding unwanted br tag

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

For some reason Im getting a `<br/>` tag from nowhere in my response from the PHP function...

Here is the ajax:

```
var paid_value = 'Paid';

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/myshop/owe_money/add_paid.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { paid_value:paid_value } ,       
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#ajax-result").html('Before');
    },  

    success: function(data) {

        $("#ajax-result").html(data);
        $('input[name="mark_as_paid"]').val(data);

    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $("#ajax-result").html('Error');
    }
});
```

And the PHP:

```
function add_paid() {
    include('../db_connect.php');

    $paid_value = $_POST['paid_value'];

    if (is_numeric($paid_value)) {
        $sql = "UPDATE paid SET first_item = $paid_value";
    } else {
        $sql = "UPDATE paid SET first_item = '".$paid_value."'";            
    }

    if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
        echo $paid_value;
    } else {
        echo "Unsuccesful".mysqli_error($connect);
    }

    die;
}

add_paid();
```

My response should simply be saying "Paid", but instead is saying "`<br />`                                      Paid".

Comment: Check the content of your server response (Firebug's Network tab will help). There's no obvious place this is coming from, so check your HTML as well.

Comment: Exactly what @MikeW said. In chrome you can use the network tab as well, have it open, and then make the ajax request and it will show up here. Click on it and then check the response to see if there is the BR tag. My guess is that its not the server.

Comment: I checked the network tab, and the <br /> is in the response there too

Comment: I have as the same you, did you find any way for this ? @Adrian

Answer (score 0):

on the face of it, it looks sound.  You'll probably find that the br is going in somewhere else.  Maybe it's even already in the file?

If it is finding it's way into the $_POST variable, you could temporarily hack the issue to use

```
 $paid_value = strip_tags($_POST['paid_value]);
```

This answer comes with no warranty whatsoever!

Comment: Thanks but this didnt fix it, I had figured it wouldnt as I checked the DB and there were no tags being added in the field. The tag only seems to get generated from the ajax response

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery code, change the `success` block to:

```
success: function(data) {
                $("#ajax-result").html(data);
                $('input[name="mark_as_paid"]').val(data);
                console.log(data)
            },
```

Open your debugger in the browser and view the console. This will write the value of data as sent from your PHP script, and may or may not have the line break in it. I suspect that the line break may be coming from the fist page but this will allow you to see this.

I cannot see any problem with the code so I think it has to do with the form/input where you are displaying the result - you have not included this.

Comment: Thanks when I try this , its still displaying the <br />

Comment: Just to confirm - you are seeing the line break tag in the debugging console?

Comment: Yep, I checked the table and theres no break, theres no <br /> tags in my code anywhere, it seems to be created with the ajax response.

Comment: and yes I can confirm Im seeing the line in the console itself

Comment: Ok. check that your PHP page that is handling the AJAX request does not have any extra white space anywhere. especially before the opening <?php tag and that at no point on that page anything else is being echoed out other that "Paid".  If that does not work you may need to post all of you code  so we can look at it, as there are parts we cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

you can use replace tag in success ajax

```
data.replace("but the br tag","");
```

but it will still exist in the database